# Do i need to lock a bool when i'm reading/writing it in two consecutive statements?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

I wonder if this is thread-safe or (if not) how i can make it safe. It gets called from a timer:

```
private volatile bool _isSynchronizing;

private void SynchronizeSessionCache(object state = null)
{
    if (_isSynchronizing)
    {
        Log.Warn($"Aborted synchronization of SessionCache with SessionManager because we are already synchronizing. Interval is: {SynchronizationInterval}");
        return;
    }

     _isSynchronizing = true;

    bool lockWasTaken = false;
    try
    {
        // some code  that doesn't need a lock ...
        // ...

        // lock this part
        Monitor.Enter(_lockObject, ref lockWasTaken);
        // main code ...
    } 
    finally  // omitted catch
    {
        _isSynchronizing = false; 
        if(lockWasTaken)
            Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
    }
}
```

My concern is that it could be possible that one thread checks `_isSynchronizing` at the beginning of his method and it's `false` at this time. Then another thread enters the body because it's not yet set to `true` by thread1. Is that possible even if `_isSynchronizing` is `volatile`? If so, what's the best way to make this method thread-safe?

If i understand it correctly `volatile` cannot prevent such race conditions but only ensures that the variable isn't cached, so all threads always read the current value.

Comment: Yes it's possible for both treads to pass over first check. But then inside method you have a lock, so you expect multiple threads to enter, so what's the idea?

Comment: @Evk: i don't expect multiple threads to enter. The `_lockObject` is used in other methods and events too which need access to shared resources. This must be locked during synchonization. It should never happen that multiple threads enter at the same time. That's why i use the `_isSynchronizing ` flag.

Comment: Well then I would just use double-checked locking here.

Comment: Make `_isSynchronizing` an `int` and then write `if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isSynchronizing, 1, 0) != 0)`. Problem solved without locks.

Comment: The idea that volatile ensures that the up-to-date value is always read in C# is false, so stop believing it. The C# specification carefully describes the actual meaning of volatile, which is that there are restrictions on how the effect of writing a volatile variable may be re-ordered with respect to other reads and writes. As I have said many times, you should read this to see if you understand how volatile access can be re-ordered: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/

Comment: In particular, the notion that there is something called the "up to date value" implies that a variable has a *consistently observable value at all moments in time*. This assumption is false; the C# specification says that without locks there is not necessarily a consistent ordering of volatile writes observed from all threads. Even in a world where everything is volatile, threads can disagree on the order in which mutations happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure the thread safety, you have to make the comparison and the assignment to a single atomic operation. Otherwise there is always a chance that another thread can pass the comparison while the assignment is being performed by the first thread. The `volatile` keyword doesn't help here, because it rather tells the compiler (and the runtime) that no optimization is allowed which could change the sequence of the read-write operations this variable is involved into.

(More about the `volatile` thing you can read in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/) great article by Eric Lippert.)

The simple (slightly slower one) solution would be to set up a critical section around the comparison and the assignment:

```
lock (_someLockObject)
{
    if (_isSynchronizing)
    {
         return;
    }

   _isSynchronizing = true;    
}
```

There is a faster solution however, but not for a `bool` variable. For an `int`, you could use the `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` method.

Let's pretend that `int _isSynchronizing = 0` means `false` and `_isSynchronizing  = 1` means `true`.

Then you can use this statement:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _isSynchronizing, 1, 0) == 1)
{
    // If the original val == 1, we're already synchronizing
    return;
}
```

This is slightly faster than using a `Monitor`, but there is no `bool` overload.

Comment: For clarity in this situation. Would be be correct to use ```Interlocked.Decrement(ref _isSynchronizing);``` or a straight assignment to zero without locks etc